# Publishing package error on assosiasion (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, publish

I have updated my Visual Studio to Update 1. Currently when I am trying to associate the package with my Store package I am getting this error:

Unable to update the package manifest. An unexpected error occurred. (HRESULT: 0x80004003)

Publishing without association works though, but as I launch 'Windows App Certification Kit' I get this error:

> Error Found: The app manifest test detected the following errors:◦The
>   revision number in the app package version and bundle version must be
>   set to 0, for example Version="10.1.2.0". This is restricted for
>   Windows Store use only.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This was resolved in VS2015 Update 2, TACO Update 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug in the new Cordova tools, the version in the config.xml (Windows tab) isn't overriding the version of the manual manifest...
So there it is

Answer (score 1):

There's a known problem with VS2015, Update 1 that prevents you from associating a Store app to a Cordova project. Instead, you can choose the option to Create App Packages which will set up the association and allow you to test it as a store app. See also: [VS2015 Update 1 Can't Associate Store App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325733/visual-studio-crashes-when-trying-to-associate-cordova-app-with-store/35469369#35469369)