# Visual Studio crashes when trying to associate Cordova app with store

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, windows-store

I'm on the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 Community (14.0.24720.00 Update 1) on Windows 10. I'm currently developing a Cordova App for Windows 10, iOS and Android using the Visual Studio Tools.

When I right click on the Project, then go Store > Associate App with the Store, I can successfully log in, see my existing apps and select the one I want, but when I try to actually associate that app with my VS project, VS just crashes.

I've already tried repairing Visual Studio through Add or Remove Programs and also cleaning out my project/solution, but none of this worked.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix in Visual Studio 2015 for this crash is now available in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. Here's a link to the installer: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691129

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Apparently, this is a known problem with VS2015 Update 1 (with the latest Cordova tools support).

The current workaround is to choose "Create App Packages" instead of "Associate App with the store." When you do this, the proper association will be generated and you can test as usual. I was successful using this approach.

Comment: Yup, this is a known issue that we're actively working on in the Visual Studio TACO team (of which I'm a part).

Comment: Have the same problem but the workaround is not working for me. It still crashes. Any ETA of a bugfix?